# Вывод двумерного массива в указанных координатах

Tags: c++, массивы, visual-c++, координаты

Необходимо вывести двумерный массив так, чтобы он корректно отображался и не смещался, в определенное место консоли с помощью **SetCursor(x, y);**
У меня он съезжает либо отображается неровно

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
enum Napravlenie { Up = 72, Left = 75, Right = 77, Down = 80, Enter = 13, Esc = 27, Space = 32 };
HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
void SetCursor(int x, int y)
{
    COORD myCoords = { x,y };
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hStdOut, myCoords);
}

void show(int mass[][10], int length = 10)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
SetCursor(20, 10);
        for (size_t j = 0; j < length; j++)
        {
            cout << mass[i][j] << '\t';
        }
        cout << endl << endl;
    }
}
void main() 
{
    int mass[10][10] = {};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            mass[i][j] = rand() % 30;
        }
    }
    show(mass);
}
```

Вывод:[image: корекктный вариант]

Comment: Приведите воспроизводимый пример программы с заполнением массива. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос, какой вывод программы должен быть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    for (size_t j = 0; j < length; j++)
    {
        // j * ШиринаЧисла + СдвигСлева, i * (ВертикальныйОтступ + 1) + СдвигСверху
        SetCursor(j * 6 + 4, i * 2 + 4);
        cout << mass[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}
```

Comment: Исправил ответ, обратите внимание.